# Running external programs through nodejs and interacting with browser through socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, socket.io, child-process

While trying to create a tool(with nodejs, socket.io) which runs an external program (e.g. a C program or a Python program), the program stops responding when it encounters the user input (it sends the line asking input to browser though).

On Server:

```
    var chunk = '';
    python.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    python.stdout.pipe(python.stdin);
        chunk += data;
        console.log(chunk);
        socket.emit('newdata', chunk);
    } );
```

On Client:

```
    socket.on('newdata', function(d){
     var output = document.getElementById('output');
     output.innerHTML = d;
   })
```

Comment: Bro/sis, don't ask people to wade through big blocks of code to figure out what you've tried and what you're aiming for, before getting to how to fix it. Please give a [minimum complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what's not working, that is, tell us how "the code fails to achieve" it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine in fact, the only problem is that the program you launched requires a user input and your node.js code is not giving it.

Tbh I don't know if you can give an input when it asks for it... but can't you pass arguments at the start of the program to avoid this user input? It's how I solved it on the same system done with Java/J2EE

Comment: Well, I want input(s) to be supplied in realtime, so passing them as arguments is not solution. What I am looking for is, the program asks for an input, user supplies that from browser and onclick it goes to the node and the program continues this way.